# Division/Remain by a Mersenne Prime

Tags: prime-numbers, integers

Is it possible to compute the integer division and remainder of an integer $x$ by a Mersenne prime $p$ using only bitwise operations?

Comment: if $A = \sum_{k=0}^K a_k 2^k$ then $A \equiv  \sum_{k=0}^K a_k 2^{k\% n} \bmod 2^n-1$, since $2^n \equiv 1 \bmod 2^n-1$ (and no need for $n$ or $2^n-1$ to be prime)

Comment: I added a reference to an algorithm here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208781