# Is there an Efficient Way to Divide by a Mersenne Prime?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, computer-science, cryptography, mersenne-numbers

Mersenne primes are used in Computer Science and Cryptography because they support fast modulo computation. If $p$ is a Mersenne prime, $n \bmod p$ can be computed with just a few add and shift operations.

Is there a well known, similarly fast, way to compute $\lfloor n/p \rfloor$?
That is a way that uses only basic operations, such as shifts, adds and perhaps multiplications, but no divisions?

It doesn't appear to follow directly from the modulus computation. I have searched for all the terms I could think of, but nothing has appeared so far.

Comment: What is the largest $a$ such that $2^a p \le n$, then how would you compute $n-2^a p$ ? Equivalently let $m = n- (n\bmod p)$ and divide $m/p$ by equating the bits one by one from the lowest.

Comment: @reuns Can you do the "equating bits one by one" efficiently though?

Comment: What do you get for the complexity ? (you can assume $n = 0 \bmod p$)

Comment: This is connected to trial "digits" of a quotient in long division.  Knuth AOCP vol. 2 has an apt discussion, as well as for the general difficulty of computing $\lfloor n/p \rfloor$ with arbitrary integer arguments.

Comment: This might be interesting: http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/mod.shtml#exmod3

Answer (score 1):

I think something like Algorithm 6 in [https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~ahasan/web_papers/technical_reports/web_lwpfi.pdf](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eahasan/web_papers/technical_reports/web_lwpfi.pdf) is what I was looking for:

```
def crandall(x, n, c):
    """ Returns divmod(x, 2**n-c) """
    q, r = x >> n, x & ((1<<n)-1)
    q_sum, r_sum = q, r
    while q > 0:
        q, r = q*c >> n, (q * c) & ((1<<n)-1)
        q_sum, r_sum = q_sum + q, r_sum + r
    t = 2**n - c
    while r_sum >= t:
        q_sum, r_sum = q_sum + 1, r_sum - t
    return q_sum, r_sum
```

Setting `c = 1` gives a division free way to divide by Mersenne primes, and for general `c` it does Pseudo-Mersenne numbers.

**Edit:** I found a more efficient algorithm for this and other operations using Mersenne primes: https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.08654

**Edit 2:** Bug corrections for Python implementation - Firstrock